# System load by HP-SNMP-Agents is high

Tags: linux, hp, snmp, hp-proliant

After installing the hp-snmp-agents on my proliant server, I noticed the system load never goes below 1. Is this normal behavior, or is it possible to reduce the load of the HP tools?

---

Update: the server is a HP Proliant DL360 G3, running Linux.
The hp-snmp-agents package is version 8.2.0, installed from the smartstart CD.
System firmware is upgraded to 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll want a bit of detail here, but I have a good idea of what your issue is. First, I'll assume that you're using Linux (due to the reference to load). Next, I'd like to know which version of the HP agents you're using. Are you using a version earlier than 8.60? If that's the case, the problem is probably due to the Lights-Out Driver agents.

In short, you'll want to stop the HP management agents with `/etc/init.d/hp-snmp-agents stop`. Edit the `exclude` line in `/opt/hp/hp-snmp-agents/cma.conf` from:

`exclude`

to

`exclude cmasm2d cpqriisd cmarackd`

Start your agents again with `/etc/init.d/hp-snmp-agents start`

Please see:
http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/ProLiant-Servers-Netservers/Proliant-Support-Pack-8-20-gt-Load-always-at-1/td-p/1069560

Also respond with your details. Which Proliant model is this? These issues were resolved in the 8.60 variant of the agents. As usual, it will also make sense to update your firmware and use the newest version of the agents.

[Proliant firmware and management software (by model)](http://h20180.www2.hp.com/apps/Nav?h_pagetype=s-002&h_lang=en&h_cc=us&h_product=241435&h_client=S-A-R163-1&h_page=hpcom&lang=en&cc=us).

Comment: Thanks, this fixes the load issue. What monitoring is lost by disabling these 3 services?

Comment: You lose the ability to monitor the ILO from the host operating system. You did not answer the questions I had about server model and version. This is a hack, but is fixed in the current versions of the management agents.

Comment: Hi ewwhite, thanks for the response. I think we just crossed our responses, I'd updated my question after replying.   -- also, what is specifically lost when the iLO is not logged? (which hardware reports?) RAID controller / memory reports?

Comment: Small update: I've fixed the issues by boldly upgrading to the v8.60 software, even though that is only listed for newer HP server models. This works, and my load issue is fixed! Since this server is used for projects/tests, I didn't mind trying this out.